# Java sort LinkedList of LinkedLists into size order

Tags: java, list, collections, comparator

I'm currently faced with this problem:  I have a LinkedList that contains several LinkedLists containing longs, so:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Long>>() overalllList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Long>();
```

After some code runs, the overall List gets filled with lists of longs of varying sizes.  What I need to do is order the overallList so that it contains the lists of longs from smallest to largest.

I hope that makes sense.

So to clarify, I need this:

```
OverallList:
    LinkedList<Long> (size 2) - first
    LinkedList<Long> (size 245) - second
    LinkedList<Long> (size 1000) - third
    ...etc
```

I'm not sure if using Collections would do this, or if I need to look at a custom comparator.  Any input or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you need custom `Comparator`.

Comment: You will need to consider that your list will have mutable elements. So it may not be ordered at one point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one example of a method to do that,

```
// A "size()" comparator 
private static Comparator<LinkedList<Long>> comp = new Comparator<LinkedList<Long>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(LinkedList<Long> o1, LinkedList<Long> o2) {
        return new Integer((o1 == null) ? 0 : o1.size()).compareTo((o2 == null) ? 0 : o2.size());
    }
};
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // LinkedList<LinkedList<Long>>() overalllList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Long>();
    // Note there is an extra () to the left of your overalllList.
    LinkedList<LinkedList<Long>> overalllList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Long>>();
    LinkedList<Long> list3 = new LinkedList<Long>();
    LinkedList<Long> list2 = new LinkedList<Long>();
    LinkedList<Long> list1 = new LinkedList<Long>();

    for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // 5, or 1000
        if (i < 2) {
            list1.add(i);
        }
        if (i < 3) { // 3, or 245.
            list2.add(i);
        }
        list3.add(i);
    }
    overalllList.add(list3);
    overalllList.add(list2);
    overalllList.add(list1);
    System.out.println("Before: " + overalllList);

    Collections.sort(overalllList, comp);
    System.out.println("After: " + overalllList);
}
```

Output is

```
Before: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1]]
After: [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<List<Long>> overalllList = new LinkedList<List<Long>>();
overalllList.add(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L));
overalllList.add(Arrays.asList(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L));
overalllList.add(Arrays.asList(9L));

Collections.sort(overalllList, new Comparator<List<Long>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<Long> list1, List<Long> list2) {
        return list1.size() - list2.size();
    }
});
```